# Microsoft Screen Capture – C# UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, screen-capture

On the following **Microsoft Screen Capture** link it shows example C# UWP app code.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture

I can’t compile the **Putting it all together** example code at the bottom of the page.

- I’ve created a new C# Blank App (Universal Windows) project in Visual
  Studio 2022 Community edition.
- Copied and pasted the ‘Putting it all together’ example code into the
  code view of the MainPage.xaml file
- Viewed the Package.appxmanifest file in the designer and selected the
  ‘Graphics Capture’ option on the Capabilities tab (as per the
  instructions on the Screen Capture link)

This showed the **Microsoft.Graphics** namespace was missing from the project when I tried to compile it. So I searched for Microsoft.Graphics in the NuGet Manager and installed Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D package (v1.0.5.1) by Microsoft.

This fixed most of the compile errors, but it showed there were still errors. One of them being the error on the following line:

```
_compositionGraphicsDevice = CanvasComposition.CreateCompositionGraphicsDevice(
    Window.Current.Compositor,
    _canvasDevice);
```

The compiler outputted:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Windows.UI.Composition.Compositor' to
> 'Microsoft.UI.Composition.Compositor'

`Window.Current.Compositor` returns `Windows.UI.Composition.Compositor` type whereas the `CanvasComposition.CreateCompositionGraphicsDevice` method is expecting `Microsoft.UI.Composition.Compositor` type as the 1st argument.

Can someone please tell me what I need to reference or do to get the example code to compile?
Thank you

Comment: i dont know these classes but can you maibe just cast them?

Comment: Looking in the Object Browser the Windows.UI.Composition.Compositor and Microsoft.UI.Composition.Compositor classes both implement the ICompositor interface, but on different namespaces. And the CanvasComposition.CreateCompositionGraphicsDevice method is expecting a Microsoft.UI.Composition.Compositor type value as the first argument. So I don't think they can be casted into a type that would fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[Win2D.uwp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Win2D.uwp/1.26.0?_src=template)** in UWP. The `Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D` you installed is for use with WinUI3 and Project Reunion.

> Win2D currently has two packages available:
>
> - **Win2D.uwp**
>
> For use with the WinUI2 (Universal Windows Platform only)
>
> - Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D
>
> For use with WinUI3 and Project Reunion

Comment: Thank you @junjie-zhu-msft. It compiles now.